# parse a fractional number into matlab from a configuration file

Tags: matlab, configuration-files

In a matlab program I have an external parameter file that needs to be read in. Like

```
a = 1/3
b = 'test'
```

Currently I use `textscan` to read this file and use `str2num` to parse the values of `a`. However, I read that `str2num` use `eval` inside, which is undesirable for safety reason: what if someone made `a = 'delete something'`, and then `str2num` will execute the string as a side effect.  `str2double` does not work for fractional numbers. Is there any better way to parse `1/3` from external file into matlab?

Comment: Though this is not likely to be triggered by someone without MATLAB knowledge, I can confirm that the weakness is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to parse input that can only be a simple number or a division, the `str2double`/`str2double` approach may be sufficient. However if you want to parse input safely in general, I would recommend restricting the input.

For example like so:

```
rawString= 'dir+3/5'
safeCharacters = ['0':'9' '+-*/\^eEij. '];

if all(ismember(rawString,safeCharacters))
   str2num(junkString)
end
```

Of course this may filter out some potentially good input like:  `str2num('rand')`

Comment: `'E'` and `'j'` are also safe (alternative versions of `'e'` and `'i'`). And you might want to permit `'.'` if decimal values are possible too. And possibly even `'*'` as it might be used both in complex values (e.g., `'1+2*i'`) and to write numbers in engineering notation as a substitute for  `'e'`/`'E'` (e.g., `'2*10^-3'`).

Comment: @horchler I agree that those additions would make for a good basis, and I have also added the simple space. Of course the safe characters can be adjusted freely as needed per usage, but keep in mind that less characters will likely be safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly search for the backslash with strfind.

```
if ~isempty(strfind(X, '/'))
   % then use str2num
else
   % use str2double, and if this returns a NaN, then it is a string
end
```

Or use `strtok` to split the string using `'/'` as a token, and use `str2double` on all resulting elements.

Comment: I think the first case still has the same problem, trying with `str2double('dir')`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use `str2num` (which is based on `eval` if you read the documentation). However, another option is `sym`. The Symbolic Math toolbox is based on `eval` as well of course, but it has input validation to avoid the potential dangers you're worried about. It is very robust and simple to use for what you need:

```
a = '1/3';
a = double(sym(a))
```

This also handles converting cell arrays of strings to vectors and matrices gracefully:

```
a={'1/3','1/33','1/333'; ...
   '2/3','2/33','2/333'};
a = double(sym(a))
```

The following unlikely input will return warnings and an error (and not delete `a` in memory):

```
b = 'delete a';
a = double(sym(b))
```

Thus you may want to use a [`try`/`catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) statement to gracefully handle cases when a user may provide invalid input:

```
try
    Xs = double(sym(X));
catch err
    if strcmp(err.id,'MATLAB:UndefinedFunction')
        error('YourFunctionName:UnknownInput','Your helpful message here.');
    else
        rethrow(err);
    end
end
```

You could equally replace the `Xs = double(sym(X));` line with a call to `str2num`.